# Munkres - Topology (book) or Tej Bahadur Singh - Introduction to Topology (book)?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, book-recommendation

I woud like a recommendation about which of these books is best for self study.

**1) Munkres - Topology** (And which edition? Pearson Limited or 2nd edition ?)

**2) Tej Bahadur Singh - Introduction to Topology, 2019**

My background in general topology is based on the breathtaking geometrical book:
"John Lee - Introduction to Topological Manifolds".
I have also read a bit of algebraic topology from this book and some notes about simply connected spaces by John Lee. This was my first touch with general topology.
Sometimes I also used the book: "Marco Mannetti - Topology" about hard concepts I could not find somewhere else.

I started with Dr. Lee's book in order to have a solid geometrical topological background, I needed for further study of Smooth Manifolds. Recently I finished the first 5 chapters of the book "John Lee - Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". I would like to say with all this information that I have maturity in this subject and particularly in a geometrical way, but I must fill some gaps-concepts about topology, that Lee's book did not include. After a long research in the internet I found that the books written by Munkres and Tej Bahadur Singh seem complete about the knowledge they provide.

Furthermore I have 2 problem books in my library that I will use as supplement, if they are needed:

**A) Lynn Arthur Steen, J. Arthur Seebach Jr. - Counterexamples in Topology**

**B) Viro O., Ivanov O., Netsvetaev N., Kharlamov V. - Elementary topology problem textbook**

My plan is to master as much as I can the general and algebraic topology so I can use them later as an important tool for Manifold Theory.

So, the best road for complete self-study is **[1. & A) & B)]** or **[2. & A) & B)]** ?

Thank you very much for any answer, I woud appreciate any help because I study this for the love of Geometry.

Comment: For algebraic topology, I would definitely recommend [Hatcher's book](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html)

Comment: @Didier thank you very much for the answer, I know about Hatcher's book but I would prefer something not so dense right now! thank you!

Comment: @SpyridwnAngelopoulos what is your goal? Are there particular things that you want to learn?

Comment: @AndresMejia I want to have as much knowledge I can take about general and algebraic topology. I have read Lee's book, which is amazing for someone to have the topological background about manifolds and build his knowledge in topology through a more geometrical approach, than the original taste of analysis an ordinary book of topology has. But the book I was reading was not complete: many theorems which exist in munkres, did not exist in Lee, different kind of examples, more problems etc. I mean,  I know topology, but I do not feel confident that I have a complete knowledge about topology.

Comment: @AndresMejia I would like to add that, I might know things about topology that Munkres does not include in his book, because my first topology book was Lee's book, so I read the topology behind manifolds. For example I have seen very very much content about quotient spaces, partitions of the unity, building homeomorphism-formulas all the time, geometrical constructions, and hard examples as the topology of grassman manifold etc, but I do not know seperation axioms very well or tychonoff theorem. I want to complete my knowledge in topology. A good geometer must know good topology..